Evaluation Framework for Neuron Network
I am looking for a framework or tool to evaluate neural network models (which could be Spiking Neural Networks or Convolutional Neural Networks). The input to this framework or tool would be a neural network model and any given dataset, and the output should include performance metrics such as TOPS,power consumption, model size, number of parameters, accuracy
Name of Evaluation Framework for Neuron Network

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
